# Do Instagram RealTime API acknowledgments count against your limit?

Tags: api, instagram

For the RealTime API, you must send an acknowledgment of receipt within 2 seconds, hitting the instagram API to do so. Does this acknowledgment count against your API rate limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it does not appear to count against your API limit.

In my view, the wording of the Instagram Developer API is a bit unclear. What the 2-seconds statement actually means is that when your designated endpoint gets hit by their RealTime server (which is notifying your endpoint that there is new media available that meets your specifications), your endpoint must accept, process, and then close the incoming connection from the RealTime server within 2 seconds.

You can then choose to hit the Instagram API to fetch the new data, or you can just ignore it. (Notably, the RealTime API notifies you that there is new data, but it does not send you that data.)